# Browse to IP/WebApp using apache

Tags: apache, suse

I have the current setup

1. OpenSuSE 12.1
2. Apache 2.2

Please note I am not a web developer or web admin at all.

I have installed redmine to test and have everything up and running.

I can browse to redmine on the local machine and over the network using x.x.x.x:3000

1. listen.conf - added Listen 3000
2. httpd.conf -
    
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/htdocs/redmine/public>
     
      Order allow, deny
      Allow from all
      AllowOverride all
3. Opened port 3000 on firewall.

What I would actually like to do is to access redmine in the following manner:

x.x.x.x/redmine

I have tried reading up on this but my skill levels with apache is just not up to scratch.

Any pointers, ideas or clear documents I could read for this?

Kind regards,

Neill

UPDATE 1

For anybody that might come across this post, I got it working.

Some info first

1. rails -v - Rails 3.2.8
2. ruby -v - ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357) [i586-linux]
3. redmine is installed at /webapps/redmine

Then,

1. Add a symbolic link:

   ln -s /webapps/redmine/public/ /srv/www/redmine
2. /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

`<VirtualHost *>`

```
ServerName serverName
DocumentRoot "/srv/www/"
Alias /redmine "/webapps/redmine/public"
ErrorLog /webapps/redmine/errorlog.log"
RailsEnv production
<Directory "/webapps/redmine/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
</Directory>
RailsBaseURI /redmine
```

`</VirtualHost>`

1. /webapps/redmine/public:

   cp dispatch.fcgi.example dispatch.cgi
2. which ruby - /usr/bin/ruby
3. /webapps/redmine/public/dispatch.cgi

   Edit First line to directory from result of which command

That is what I did to get it working so hopefully it will help somebodyt else out there.

Regards

Neill

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that might come across this post, I got it working.

Some info first

```
rails -v - Rails 3.2.8
ruby -v - ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357) [i586-linux]
redmine is installed at /webapps/redmine
```

Then,

```
Add a symbolic link:

ln -s /webapps/redmine/public/ /srv/www/redmine
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

ServerName serverName
DocumentRoot "/srv/www/"
Alias /redmine "/webapps/redmine/public"
ErrorLog /webapps/redmine/errorlog.log"
RailsEnv production

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

RailsBaseURI /redmine

```
/webapps/redmine/public:

cp dispatch.fcgi.example dispatch.cgi

which ruby - /usr/bin/ruby

/webapps/redmine/public/dispatch.cgi

Edit First line to directory from result of which command
```

That is what I did to get it working so hopefully it will help somebodyt else out there.

Regards

Neill